# Tornado: Updated data from mysql not showing in frontend served by tornado. Only shows after restarting the server

Tags: python, mysql, angularjs, tornado

I have a tornado backend which serves an Angular frontend. On updating the database, the updated data is not being fetched by the tornado api. It only appears after I restart the server. Can someone please help me with this? I want the data fetched to be updated real-time.

AngularJS ajax request:

```
   $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:9915/api/"
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.data = response.data;
            sharedData.set(response.data);
            for (var i = $scope.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                var coverageVal = $scope.data[i].Coverage;
                var coverageHealth = $scope.data[i].Health;

                if (coverageVal >= 95.00) {
                    $scope.data[i]["colorCoverage"] = "cyan";
                } else if (coverageVal >= 90.00 && coverageVal < 95.00) {
                    $scope.data[i]["colorCoverage"] = "warning";
                } else {
                    $scope.data[i]["colorCoverage"] = "danger";
                }

                if (coverageHealth >= 95.00) {
                    $scope.data[i]["colorHealth"] = "cyan";
                } else if (coverageHealth >= 90.00 && coverageHealth < 95.00) {
                    $scope.data[i]["colorHealth"] = "warning";
                } else {
                    $scope.data[i]["colorHealth"] = "danger";
                }

            }
        }, function myError(err) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Tornado api to fetch data:

```
     class ApiRequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
           cur = conn.cursor()
           cur.execute("SELECT * from db.table")
           res = []
           for row in cur:
              res.append(row)
           self.write(json.dumps(res))
```

Comment: Isolated transactions?

Comment: yes, they are isolated. The data is updated from another script not handled by the tornado api.

Comment: Do you confirm that frontend part (angular) makes the ajax request? Show some code, it might help

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: How do you update the `db.table`? Do you commit changes? If not, do you have auto commit enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You don't said what mysql connector are you using, but if you are using mysqldb try something like this:

```
class ApiRequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       cur = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) 
       cur.execute("SELECT * from db.table")
       rows = cur.fetchall()
       self.write(json.dumps(rows))
```

Also I recommend you to start using asyncio calls, for example using python 3.5 or up, you can use the aiomysql

```
class ApiRequestHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
       cur = await conn.cursor() 
       await cur.execute("SELECT * from db.table")
       rows = await cur.fetchall()
       self.write(json.dumps(rows))
```